# Access a accdb file (MS Access 2007) from resources

Tags: vb.net, resources, ms-access

probably this is a simple question but because i have never used resources like that i can not think how should i do it. 
I am writing a very simple program that connects to a accdb file (Microsoft Access 2007 file) and returns some results in a datagridview. Everything is fine. Now because we have to deploy this program in many computers i publish it so everyone we want can install it and have updates. What i wanted to do is to make the database file part of the program which i did it by adding it to the resources. My problem is that i do not know what connection string to enter in order to access it in my resources.
My previous connectionstring before i deploy it was this

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\bl.accdb;Persist Security Info=True
```

What should i change in the data source in order to access the same file in my resources? Or am i wrong and this is not possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. All you need to do is point the datasource to the location of the resources direcory, which by default is adjacent to the application itself. You could determine this at runtime by using:

```
Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\DatabaseName.accdb"
```